# Python For loop to divide value of function on each iteration

Tags: python

Can you guys help on how to use a for range loop decrease/divide the value of a function on each iteration.

When first time the function run its value would be 100% then 80% , then 60%...

I am working on turtle graphics. Any help will be appreciated

```
def scene(housesize):
   for i in range (3):
     hs = housesize*0.8
     myhouse(hanzi, hs)
     hanzi.pu()
     hanzi.goto(200,20)
     hanzi.pd()
scene(100)
```

> Here hanzi is my turtle and housesize is the size i want to decrease on each iteration

Comment: You just need to spend a bit more time thinking about what you're doing, right now every iteration you're setting `hs = housesize * 0.8`, but because `housesize` is constant, `hs` will be as well.

Comment: Actually the problem is not necessarily that `housesize` is constant but that `housesize * 0.8` is constant ;) (=> there are many ways to skin a cat....)

Comment: any solution would be very helpful because i am new to python. Thanks

Comment: @AirasKhan We're not here to just give solutions to problems, especially (relatively) basic ones, sit down with a pen and paper and go through your program line by line, see where the problem is being caused and spend time thinking how to fix it. Programming (and the mindset behind it) takes time and practice to learn.

Comment: @AirasKhan the problem is not specific to Python, it's most an algorithmic one (and not a complex one FWIW). You already have a couple hints in the previous comments that should get you started if you re-read your code and explain (in details) to a rubber duck  what each line does. Well, you can use something else than a rubber duck actually (a teddy bear would do). cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers rubber duck, pen and paper (there are indeed many ways to skin a cat ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to change the size on each iteration when the function scene is called once the you can simply do the following :

```
def scene(housesize):

         houseSizeList =  [100*housesize, 80*housesize, 60*housesize]

         for myhouseSize in houseSizeList:
                  hs = myhouseSize*0.8
                  myhouse(hanzi, hs)
                  hanzi.pu()
                  hanzi.goto(200,20)
                  hanzi.pd()
scene(100)
```

This will work for reducing the house size for 100%, 80%, 60%.

If you want to reduce it till 0% then the list should be created for all 10 cases or you can just do the following.

```
def scene(housesize):
         reductionFactor = 100
         for i in range (3):
                  hs = housesize*0.8*reductionFactor
                  myhouse(hanzi, hs)
                  hanzi.pu()
                  hanzi.goto(200,20)
                  hanzi.pd()
                  reductionFactor = reductionFactor - 20
scene(100)
```

reductionFactor will start from 100% and reduce by 20 on each iteration.

hope this helps

Comment: i was missing this reductionfactor = reductionfactor - 20